# Serialize RxSwift

Tags: concurrency, rx-swift

I'm working on my own OAuth2 implementation using RxSwift. In order to authenticate a request I have an Authenticator that fetches and stores the access token. So if I have a valid access token, the Authenticator will return it right away otherwise it will perform a request to the server. That's exactly what `accessTokenRequest()` does.

```
request = authenticator
            .accessTokenRequest()
            .map(toAuthorizationHeader)
            .flatMap {self.actualRequest(withEndpoint: endpoint, authHeader: $0)}
```

The problem is that when I have multiple requests requesting authentication and no valid access token stored, the Authenticator will make multiple access token requests as well. This is not desirable, as ideally only the first access token request should be performed and all the subsequent requests should wait until the Authenticator finishes fetching the access token.

Basically I would like to serialize the function `accessTokenRequest()`, much like a critical region.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

This is the simplified content of the `accessTokenRequest()` function

```
func accessTokenRequest() -> Observable<OAuth2Credential> {
    if let credential = self.cachedCredential where !credential.isExpired  {

        // All subsequent requests should already enter here and return right away

        return Observable.just(credential)
    }

    ...

    // First request should reach here and request access token from the server.

    return NetworkClient.AccessToken()
            .doOnNext(cacheCredential)
}
```

Comment: If you want to stop sequence when your access token sin't valid, you have to check your token in accessTokenRequest() function. If token isn't valid - return Observable.error() and use catchError() RxSwift operator.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Not sure if I understand what you mean. I don't want to error out the sequence. I just want to pause the subsequent requests until the access token request of the first "request" finishes and then use the cached credential instead of making new access token requests. I've updated the question with the content of the accessTokenRequest() function

Comment: I really want to help you, but I can't to reproduce your error. Can you show me part of your code use Github or add more code? For example, I didn't understand why you use .doOnNext(cacheCredential). Which sense of using this operator in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this question has been here for a while, so I will give the answer anyway for anyone actually needing this in the future.

There are a couple of solutions, let's see how to achieve this in different ways.

#### Without caching

If you don't need caching, you can transform `accessTokenRequest()` into a share and replay observable with `shareReplay(1)`. This means the inner observable will fire a single request and then share the result to all the subscriptions or connected observables, so the change would be:

```
func accessTokenRequest() -> Observable<OAuth2Credential> {
    // First request should reach here and request access token from the server.
    return NetworkClient.AccessToken().shareReplay(1)
}
```

#### With caching

The updated code looks good for a caching solution, but here I would also add a `shareReplay`, I don't see the point to perform the inner task every time this observable is requires, so the side-effect gets shared. Of course this is a good solution if it's unlikely that the call will fail, in case I would add also a `retry`, to avoid the observable being terminated after a failure.